# What does it take to be considered one of the "chasidei umos ha'olam"?

Tags: gentiles

For a non-Jew to attain the status of "chasidei umos ha'olam" does he/she have to accept/believe that there is one God who is the Elokei Yisroel and has chosen the Jewish people to be his chosen people? Or is enough that the non-Jews had pity on Jews and saved/helped them?

Comment: Why do you assume that either of those two are appropriate to warrant the status? Who says that there even is such a status? Consider editing to clarify.

Comment: See Hilkhot Issurei Biah ([14:7](http://mechon-mamre.org/i/5114.htm)).

Comment: I recall an aggadata in eyn ya'akov about the specifications for chasidei umos ha'olam but sadly don't recall the location. does this jog anyone's memory?

Comment: It is a very interesting question. Possibily, we can imagine someone who believes 100% but did not help Jewish people during second World Ware, and someone who is not intellectualy oriented by religion and acted to help Jewish People.

Answer (score 1):

The Rambam (Melachim 8:11) appears to require the Chasidei Umos HaOlam to accept the commandments of bnei Noach were commanded to Moshe on Har Sinai. There's no question Hashem will give every wonderfully merciful non-Jew his/her just rewards, just as He gives all living creatures their due merit (see Rashi on Shemos 22:30), but not necessarily will they have the benefits of Chasidei Umos HaOlam.